# How it works find_by_* in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

May be its weird for some people about the question. By looking at the syntax its identifiable as **class method**.

```
Model.find_by_*
```

So if its class method it should be defined either in **model** we created or in

```
ActiveRecord::Base
```

So my question is how rails manages to add these methods and makes us available.

Examples like

```
 Model.find_by_id
 Model.find_by_name
 Model.find_by_status
```

and etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look at `ActiveRecord::FinderMethods`. [Here](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/find_by_attributes) you can find more details.

Internally, it fires a `WHERE` query based on attributes present in `find_by_attributes`. It returns the first matching object.

```
def find_by_attributes(match, attributes, *args)
  conditions = Hash[attributes.map {|a| [a, args[attributes.index(a)]]}]
  result = where(conditions).send(match.finder)

  if match.bang? && result.nil?
    raise RecordNotFound, "Couldn't find #{@klass.name} with #{conditions.to_a.collect {|p| p.join(' = ')}.join(', ')}"
  else
    yield(result) if block_given?
    result
  end
end
```

There is also `find_all_by_attributes` that returns all matching records.

Answer (score 3):

Rails are using ruby metaprogramming `method_missing` for that. The method `find_by_name` is not in a model, instead of this rails are taking `name` as first argument and it calls it like `find_by(name: ?)` which is calling `where(name: ?).take`

Comment: Thank you I am very grateful, I got to know about method_missing.

Comment: @Argonous How metaprogramming method_missing comes in this situation please explain